# Is it possible to set custom mapping for index in logstash but not in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping, output, logstash

There's input, filter and then output in Logstash main coding.

Is it possible to set custom mapping in

```
output
    { elasticsearch {

}
```

If it is possible, how do I set it?
With this example:

```
    "mappings" : {
  "_default_" : {
   "properties" : {
"service" : { "type" : "integer" },
"rule" : { "type" : "integer" },
"ICMP Type" : { "type" : "integer" },
"ICMP Code" : { "type" : "integer" },
"ip_offset" : { "type" : "integer" },
"ip_id" : { "type" : "integer" },
"ip_len" : { "type" : "integer" },
"Confidence Level" : { "type" : "integer" },
"fragments_dropped" : { "type" : "integer" },
"Severity" : { "type" : "integer" },
"serial_num" : { "type" : "integer" },
"during_sec" : { "type" : "integer" },
"Attack info" : {"type": "string", "index" : "not_analyzed" },
"peer gateway" : {"type": "string", "index" : "not_analyzed" }
```

Answer (score 1):

Logstash comes with a default template that is used when writing documents to elasticsearch.

If you'd like to change the default, you can update your config and pass it the location of a template file.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-template

Answer (score 0):

You can use template and template_overwrite fields like that :

```
 elasticsearch {
    template => "/tttttttttttt/elasticsearch-logstash-template.json"
    index => "logstash-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    cluster=>"cluster"
    template_overwrite => true
}
```